# Primefaces strange attributes after failed validation

Tags: java, validation, jsf, primefaces

I am having a strange problem with PrimeFaces. I've written a sign up form where all fields are mandatory. Almost every field has a custom internationalized converter- or validator-message.

There are two error scenarios (with and without AJAX):

- **without AJAX**: After pressing the command button all validator messages are getting displayed correctly. The problem is that after a failed validation the font color of the input fields changes to white. You can only see the entered text when selecting it.
- **with AJAX**: After pressing the command button all validator messages are getting displayed correctly and the font color of the fields does not change. The input fields are focusable. Everything works perfectly fine except that the action listener method doesn't get called.

No exceptions get thrown whatsoever. There are no error messages or things like that. I even tried changing the PrimeFaces version (I am currently using 6.1) and using the form without any styling, div containers in it and surrounding HTML tags. At first I thought that some CSS div was overlapping the form after validation, but that was not the case.

My code:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-noborder">
        <!-- MESSAGES -->
        <p:messages id="msgs" closable="true"/>
        <!-- E-MAIL -->
        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="#{msgs.email_label} *"/>
        <p:inputText id="email" name="email" required="true"
                     requiredMessage="#{msgs.email_format_message}" value="#{regCon.email}"
                     validatorMessage="#{msgs.email_format_message}">
            <f:validateRegex
                    pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="#{msgs.username_label} *"/>
        <p:inputText id="username" name="username" required="true"
                     requiredMessage="#{msgs.username_format_message}" value="#{regCon.username}"
                     validatorMessage="#{msgs.username_format_message}">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15}"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <!-- PASSWORD -->
        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="#{msgs.password_label} *"/>
        <p:password id="password" name="password" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="#{msgs.password_format_message}" match="password_rep"
                    value="#{regCon.password}" validatorMessage="#{msgs.password_format_message}">
            <f:validateRegex
                    pattern="((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,40})"/>
        </p:password>
        <!-- REPEAT PASSWORD -->
        <h:outputLabel for="password_rep" value="#{msgs.password_repeat_label} *"/>
        <p:password id="password_rep" name="password_rep" required="true" value="#{regCon.passwordRepeat}"
                    requiredMessage="#{msgs.password_repeat_required_message}"/>
        <!-- FIRSTNAME -->
        <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="#{msgs.firstname_label} *"/>
        <p:inputText id="firstname" name="firstname" required="true"
                     requiredMessage="#{msgs.firstname_required_message}" value="#{regCon.firstname}">
        </p:inputText>
        <!-- LASTNAME -->
        <h:outputLabel for="lastname" value="#{msgs.lastname_label} *"/>
        <p:inputText id="lastname" name="lastname" required="true"
                     requiredMessage="#{msgs.lastname_required_message}" value="#{regCon.lastname}">
        </p:inputText>
        <!-- PHONE -->
        <h:outputLabel for="phone" value="#{msgs.phonenumber_label} *"/>
        <p:inputText id="phone" name="phone" required="true"
                     requiredMessage="#{msgs.phone_format_message}" value="#{regCon.phoneNumber}"
                     validatorMessage="#{msgs.phone_format_message}">
            <f:validateRegex
                    pattern="\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <!-- BIRTHDAY -->
        <h:outputLabel for="birthday" value="#{msgs.birthday_label} *"/>
        <p:inputMask id="birthday" name="birthday" required="true"
                     requiredMessage="#{msgs.birthday_format_message}"
                     value="#{regCon.dateOfBirth}" mask="#{msgs.birthday_mask}"
                     converterMessage="#{msgs.birthday_format_message}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{msgs.birthday_pattern}"/>
        </p:inputMask>
        <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.registration_button}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" ajax="false"
                         update=":form:msgs"
                         process=":form:email :form:username :form:password password_rep :form:firstname :form:lastname :form:phone :form:birthday"
                         actionListener="#{regCon.register()}"/>
        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="#{msgs.reset_button}" update=":form:msgs"
                         process=":form:email :form:username :form:password :form:password_rep firstname :form:lastname :form:phone :form:birthday"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It seems like there is something wrong with the bootstrap theme.

I don't exactly know what exactly caused it, but after several hours of useless troubleshooting I am just glad that I've solved it...

Comment: That's true but I'd love to know what the exact problem is.